# Doctrine : Which syntax for GROUP_CONCAT with a CASE WHEN?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony, group-concat, case-when

I have this SQL query which works fine in phpMyAdmin :

```
SELECT `Tag_Type_Code`, `Tag_Type`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Tag_Code` ORDER BY `Tag_Name`) as tagCode,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Tag_Name` ORDER BY `Tag_Name`) as tagName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN isnull(`Tag_Picto`) THEN 'NULL' ELSE `Tag_Picto` END ORDER BY `Tag_Name`) as tagPicto
FROM tags
WHERE `modele_code` = "MYCODE"
GROUP BY `Tag_Type_Code`
ORDER BY `tag_Type` ASC
```

And I want to do it in **Doctrine and Symfony3**, I tried this but I have a syntax error near the CASE WHEN.

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT tag.typeCode, tag.type,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tag.code ORDER BY tag.name) as tagCode,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name ORDER BY tag.name) as tagName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag.picto IS NULL THEN "NULL" ELSE tag.picto END ORDER BY tag.name) as tagPicto
    FROM AppBundle:Tag tag
    WHERE tag.modelCode = :code
    GROUP BY tag.typeCode
    ORDER BY tag.type ASC'
)->setParameter('code', $modelCode)
->getResult();
```

Or this :

```
'SELECT tag.typeCode, tag.type,
    CASE WHEN tag.picto IS NULL THEN "NULL" ELSE tag.picto END as picto
    GROUP_CONCAT(tag.code ORDER BY tag.name) as tagCode,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name ORDER BY tag.name) as tagName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(picto ORDER BY tag.name) as tagPicto
FROM AppBundle:Tag tag
WHERE tag.modelCode = :code
GROUP BY tag.typeCode
ORDER BY tag.type ASC'
```

I also tried to use IfElse and IfNull extensions from [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/config/mysql.yml) but I can't find the correct syntax.

**This query works without the CASE WHEN.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with double quotes at `"NULL"`, use single quotes and escape them:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT tag.typeCode, tag.type,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tag.code ORDER BY tag.name) as tagCode,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name ORDER BY tag.name) as tagName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag.picto IS NULL THEN \'NULL\' ELSE tag.picto END ORDER BY tag.name) as tagPicto
    FROM AppBundle:Tag tag
    WHERE tag.modelCode = :code
    GROUP BY tag.typeCode
    ORDER BY tag.type ASC'
)->setParameter('code', $modelCode)
->getResult();
```

Comment: I can't test again with NULL because I change my values in my table. Apparently a GROUP_CONCAT and a CASE WHEN don't work when they are in the same query, I posted this question here : https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/issues/222

Comment: However, I should have used setParameter() in my query to set NULL value : `CASE WHEN tag.picto = :search THEN :replace ELSE tag.picto END` [...] `->setParameters(array('search' => NULL, 'replace' => 'NULL'));`